# Deactivate click-event for a cell in a specific row and a specific column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event on each row but I want to disable it for a specific cell in the row who has a classname "doc" on the seventh column.

I have this code.

```
$('#table').on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {})
```

I tried to remove the cell by removing it in my selector but it doesnt works

```
$('#table').on('click', 'tbody tr:not(.doc td:eq(6))', function () {})
```

Thank you

Comment: This might be easier if you only _removed_ the event handler for that specific element, after you first simply add it for all. Alternatively, you could do this _inside_ the handler function - check whether the triggering element was that specific cell, and if so return directly.

Comment: Do you have a example ?

Comment: No, not for trivialities like that, not if you don’t present at least your own try first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to stop propagation when this child's click is fired

```js
$('table')
  .on('click', 'tbody tr.doc td:nth-child(3)', e => {
    console.log('cell clicked')
    e.stopPropagation();
  })
  .on('click', 'tbody tr', e => {
    console.log('row clicked', $(e.currentTarget).index())
  });
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

table tbody {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table tbody tr {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

table tbody tr td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="doc">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td style="background: blue;">3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="doc">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td style="background: blue;">3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. 
How to retrieve the row ? console.log($(this))  
$this was not the row but the document.
Edit: I have it. It was e.currentTarget

Comment: `$(this)` is the Document because i'm using `arrow function` from ES6, the context is the global object with this syntax. That's why you have to use `$(e.currentTarget) ` like you said

Comment: If you had another row <tr class="doc">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td style="background: blue;">3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
It take only the first and not another

Comment: You're right, because `eq(2)` take all child of `.doc` row, there is only one child per position. Use `nth-child(3)` instead (index it's not the same)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Attach events on `td` instead of `tr`.

```
$('#table').on('click', 'tbody tr:not(.doc) td:not(:eq(6))', function () {})
```

Comment: It remove all the column. I would like only row with classname "doc" in that column